# CSV to Specific XML with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I am trying to use powershell to convert a csv to an xml table. Is there a way that you can specify exactly what the xml will output.

```
Example CSV input: 
TIME,TEMP,HUMID,DEWPT
"03/07/2012 12:04:59",72.1,73.2,62.5
"03/07/2012 11:34:53",71.9,73.8,62.5
"03/07/2012 11:04:46",71.8,74.6,62.7
"03/07/2012 10:34:39",72.3,72.6,62.4
"03/07/2012 10:04:33",71.9,72.1,61.9

Example XML output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <chart>
- <series>
  <value xid="0">03/07/2012 00:02:06</value> 
  <value xid="1">03/07/2012 00:32:17</value> 
  <value xid="2">03/07/2012 01:02:26</value> 
  <value xid="3">03/07/2012 01:32:35</value> 
  <value xid="4">03/07/2012 02:02:42</value>
  </series>
- <graphs>
- <graph gid="0" color="#32CD32" axis="right" title="Temperature">
  <value xid="0">43.1</value> 
  <value xid="1">44.0</value> 
  <value xid="2">43.6</value> 
  <value xid="3">43.1</value> 
  <value xid="4">42.7</value> 
  </graph>
- <graph gid="1" color="#FFD700" axis="left" title="Humidity">
  <value xid="0">64.6</value> 
  <value xid="1">100.0</value> 
  <value xid="2">57.7</value> 
  <value xid="3">71.6</value> 
  <value xid="4">44.3</value> 
  </graph>
  <graph gid="2" color="#8B008B" axis="left" title="Dewpoint">
  <value xid="0">30.4</value>
  <value xid="1">44</value>
  <value xid="2">28.4</value>
  <value xid="3">32.9</value>
  <value xid="4">22.6</value>
  </graph>
  </graphs>
  </chart>
```

The data may not line up 100%, I did not grab each sample piece from the same place, but you should get the drift. Is something like this possible?

Also... I maintain a large master-csv. Every hour two records are added to it. Is it possible to make the csv-to-xml increment smartly like that, or will I have to run the script against the master-csv each time. I know it will work running against the master-csv, but I am worried over time that it will take longer and longer as the list continues to grow. If I am able to add just the new entries, that would make it go much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
 $head = @'
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <chart>
 <series>
 '@

 $series = @'
 '@

 $temp_graph = @'
 </series>
 <graphs>
 <graph gid="0" color="#32CD32" axis="right" title="Temperature">

 '@

 $humid_graph = @'
 <graph gid="1" color="#FFD700" axis="left" title="Humidity">

 '@

 $dewpt_graph = @'
 <graph gid="2" color="#8B008B" axis="left" title="Dewpoint">

 '@

 $end = @'
 </graphs>
 </chart>
 '@

 $i = 0

 import-csv file.csv |
 foreach-object {

 $series += @"
 <value xid="$i">$($_.TIME)</value>

 "@

 $temp_graph += @"
 <value xid="$i">$($_.TEMP)</value>

 "@

 $humid_graph += @"
 <value xid="$i">$($_.HUMID)</value>

 "@

 $dewpt_graph += @"
 <value xid="$i">$($_.DEWPT)</value>

 "@

 $i++
 }
 $temp_graph,$humid_graph,$dewpt_graph | foreach {$_ += '<\graph>'
 $head + $series + $temp_graph + $humid_graph + $dewpt_graph + $end
```

Comment: I am getting errors when I try this code:
The string starting:
At line:1 char:9
+ $head =  <<<< @'
must have the terminator: '@ at the beginning of the line.
At line:29 char:2

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '=' operator.
At line:1 char:7

Comment: Copy/past error.  The terminating '@ and "@ must be the very beginning of the line.

Comment: You are right.. Once I fixed that, it worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well I have found another problem. There are no closing </graph> tags on Temp and Humid. I tried adding them to the script and got odd formatting. I tried to add it at the beginning of the next section.

Comment: I tested more with the original script and it was working on one machine and having issues on another. The one it was having issues with is an older version of powershell. Could that make a difference? Also, the new script you posted. Not having any luck with it on either machine, adding the </graph>. But even with it not adding that it's still having issues at the beginning. Going to revisit this on Monday. May have to use a machine that has an earlier version of powershell.

Comment: Since it's working on the newer machine that will be doing it in the future. I am good to go with this. Have another issue, but will post another topic for it. Thanks for all of your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

This following script incrementally adds data to the xml (using regex and replace functionality). The csv file `input.csv` should contain only the new entries.

```
# filename: test.ps1

function Get-ScriptDirectory
{

$Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}
$csvpath = join-path (get-scriptdirectory) input.csv
$xmlpath = join-path (get-scriptdirectory) output.xml

if (!(test-path $xmlpath)) {
  @"
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <chart>
  <series>
  </series>
  <graphs>
  <graph gid="0" color="#32CD32" axis="right" title="Temperature">
  </graph>
  <graph gid="1" color="#FFD700" axis="left" title="Humidity">
  </graph>
  <graph gid="2" color="#8B008B" axis="left" title="Dewpoint">
  </graph>
  </graphs>
  </chart>
"@ | out-file -encoding "UTF8" $xmlpath
}

$xml = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($xmlpath)



$data = import-csv $csvpath

$counter = [int](([regex]‘xid="(\d*)"’).matches($xml) | foreach {$_.Groups[1].Value} | %{[int] $_} | sort | select -last 1)
$series = $null;$temp_graph = $null;$humid_graph = $null;$dewpt_graph = $null

$data | %{
$counter++
$series += @"
 <value xid="$counter">$($_.TIME)</value>

"@

 $temp_graph += @"
 <value xid="$counter">$($_.TEMP)</value>

"@

 $humid_graph += @"
 <value xid="$counter">$($_.HUMID)</value>

"@

 $dewpt_graph += @"
 <value xid="$counter">$($_.DEWPT)</value>

"@
}
$xml = $xml -replace "</series>","$series</series>"
$xml = $xml -replace "</graph>\r*\n*\s*<graph gid=`"1`"","$temp_graph</graph><graph gid=`"1`""
$xml = $xml -replace "</graph>\r*\n*\s*<graph gid=`"2`"","$humid_graph</graph><graph gid=`"2`""
$xml = $xml -replace "</graph>\r*\n*\s*</graphs>","$dewpt_graph</graph></graphs>"

$xml | out-file -encoding "UTF8" $xmlpath
```

Comment: This sort of worked. It incrementally added the time and the dewpoint entries, but the humidity and temperature did not update.